# Why would you use an img element to request a non-image URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

After being asked to investigate a slow page load I noticed this in the HTML:

```
<img src="/ajax?action=askedAboutCookies" style="display:none" width="0" height="0" alt="" />
```

When the page loads, it obviously makes the request, but it doesn't return and simply waits until it times out.

The URL `/ajax?action=askedAboutCookies` actually points to a servlet that doesn't return an image, it (when it works) returns JSON (a very basic object, returning a boolean value).

Why would anyone do this? All our pages use jQuery, so I would have thought it was easiest to use their Ajax convenience methods for any calls like that?

Comment: I have seen this in a different scenario but with emails. It is a way to know who read an email, but I don't see why they would put it on a normal page, instead of doing a normal request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are just pinging the server to track the user. There is no worry if XMLHttpRequest object is enabled or if JavaScript is enabled. Only time this type of call fails is when images are disabled.

Comment: In that case, do you think a more acceptable approach would be to have the img element wrapped in `noscript`? Then we could have script perform the call otherwise, and use connection timeouts etc?

Comment: Why does the service have problems? That would be my first question I would answer. Second is do we only want to track people with JavaScript disabled this way? It is a business decision.